# How can a put a one child element value into an ArrayList in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have difficulties about the XmlPullParser event which is tagging all the elements but how can I store one child element into ArrayList?

this is my xml file:

```
<site>
    <name>Brake and Break</name>
    <link>https://sampleactivity.000webhostapp.com/lesson_1.mp3</link>
        <set>When teaching my daughter how to drive, I told her if she didn't hit the brake in time she would break the car's side mirror.</set>
        <set>You shouldn’t brake as often as you do. You are going to break your car’s brakes.</set>
        <set>I think this relationship is moving too fast for me. Maybe it's best to just hit the brake than to completely break up.</set>
    <image>https://sampleactivity.000webhostapp.com/stckOvflw.png</image>
</site>
```

In my xml file I have element name **SET** so how can a store all the set elements and attributes into an array list?

here is my xmlpullparser.java code:

```
switch (eventType) {
                case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:

                    if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase(KEY_SITE)) {

                        curStackSite = new StackSite();
                    }
                    break;


                case XmlPullParser.TEXT:

                    curText = xpp.getText();
                    break;


                case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                    if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase(KEY_SITE)) {

                        stackSites.add(curStackSite);
                    } else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase(KEY_NAME)) {

                        curStackSite.setName(curText);
                    } else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase(KEY_LINK)) {

                        curStackSite.setLink(curText);
                    } else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase(KEY_SET)) {
                        ArrayList<String> wew = new ArrayList<String>();
                        wew.add(curText);
                        curStackSite.setAlAbout(wew); <--- How can I store all element to arraylist here?
                        curStackSite.setSet(curText);
                    } else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase(KEY_IMAGE_URL)) {

                        curStackSite.setImgUrl(curText);
                    }
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
```

i have tried to us dom parsing but still doesn't work much really in my code.

UPDATE:

this is my stacksite value:

```
public class StackSite {
private String name;
private String link;
private String about;
private List<String> AlAbout;
private String id;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getLink() {
    return link;
}
public void setLink(String link) {
    this.link = link;
}

public String getAbout() {
    return about;
}
public void setAbout(String about) {this.about = about;}

public List<String> getAlAbout() {
    return AlAbout;
}
public void setAlAbout(List<String> AlAbout) {this.AlAbout = AlAbout;}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "StackSite [name=" + name + ", link=" + link + ", about="
            + about + ", Array sets=" + AlAbout + "]";
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `StackSite` class had a member as such:

```
List<String> allSets;
```

and the constructor of `StackSite` initialized `allSets` to an empty list:

```
allSets = new ArrayList<>();
```

then in the `END_TAG` case where `tagName.equalsIgnoreCase(KEY_SET)` you'd simply add the set text:

```
curStackSite.allSets.add(curText);
```

would add a separate entry in the `allSets` list for each `<set>…</set>` encountered.

At the end of parsing the `allSets` list member of `StackSite` contains 0 or more entries for set contents.

As for attributes you'd probably want to create a new class for a `StackSiteSet` which contains the `String` set text and attributes fields rather than treating sets as just the String.

So your `END_TAG` processing for `</set>` should look like:

```
} else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase(KEY_SET)) {
    // Get the list and add another element to it.
    curStackSite.getAlAbout().add(curText);
}
```

Comment: i tried to put the instructions you given to me but still the value of the set display only the last set . i tried it like this List<String> allSets;
                            allSets = new ArrayList<>();
                            allSets.add(curText);
                            curStackSite.setAlAbout(allSets); setAlabout contains list<String> when a getAlabout it will return me only the last set sentence not all set.

Comment: Added the `END_TAG` processing for the set for clarity.